# Calling jQuery function on Master Page body onload: 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: function is undefined

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a master page which includes the following script:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
 <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
 
 <script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>    
 <script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>  

 <link href="<%=Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css") %>" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" />  
 <link href="<%=Url.Content("~/Content/jquery-ui/pepper-grinder/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.css") %>" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" />  

 <script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <% if ( false ) { %>
   <script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>    
 <% } %>


 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {

         $(function hideMessage() {
             $('.sessionMessage').delay(5000).fadeOut(2000);
         })


   $('[id $=Link]').click(function () {
    var txt = $(this).attr("id").substr(0, $(this).attr("id").length - 4);
    $.ajax({
     url: this.href,
     cache: false,
     success: function (result) {
      $('[id ^=' + txt + '][id $=Table]').append($(result));
     },
     error: function (xhr, err) {
      alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status + "\nresponseText: " + xhr.responseText);
     }
    });
    return false;
   });
  });
 </script>
```

In the same master page, on the body tag, I call the hideMessage function:

```html
<body onload="hideMessage();">
```

When I debug the application, I get the following message:

> 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'hideMessage' is undefined

I've been trying every permutation of script location and nothing seems to affect the validity of this tiny little script.  All the other scripts seem to be loading fine, and the application runs (at least initially).

Comment: try calling `hideMessage()` direct under `document.ready()`

Comment: @Satindersingh You mean just call the function after declaring it, outside the body tag?  Edit: I tried that, same result.  Very strange...

Comment: If you want to call like < body onload='fnNAme()' then create your function outside the document.ready check have written it in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you calling your function like `<body onload='fn_name()'` then create your func outside `document.ready()`

```
<head>
    <script>
      function hideMessage(){
        alert("Hello world");
      }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="hideMessage();">
    hello world ...
    </body>
```

OR

Instead of calling `<body onload='fn_name()'` direct call in ready function as i mentioned in my 1st comment .i.e

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       helloWorld(); // when dom is ready this function gets call

      function helloWorld(){
          alert("helloWorld");        
      }
});

</script>
<body>
hello world

</body>
```

Comment: I marked your answer because it got me on the right track...I had to remove the '$' from the function call.  Not sure why it was there in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can defined the function outside the  $(document).ready function and then call it whenever you need

<script type="text/javascript">

function  hideMessage(){
$('.sessionMessage').delay(5000).fadeOut(2000);
}
        $(document).ready(function () {

           hideMessage();


            $('[id $=Link]').click(function () {
                var txt = $(this).attr("id").substr(0, $(this).attr("id").length - 4);
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.href,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('[id ^=' + txt + '][id $=Table]').append($(result));
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, err) {
                        alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status + "\nresponseText: " + xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```